# MySQL Wildcard strict words occurance search

Tags: mysql

I have problem with MySQL Wildcard search. What i am try to achieve is - wildcard search but it should be very strict about the words occurrence.

For example : i want to search the word "Science", it will bring out  all the word that have Science on it, but it will restrict from bringing out close words like Score, scrabber, etc.

I need help please, thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this is not possible. You can use tags for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

read aboud soundex levenstein and metaphone string functions. Here is a start http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,199681,199681#msg-199681

Besides, I believe SOLR would be a better candidate for such search.